# <a> tag in chrome causing failed network error in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, pdf, href

I implemented a simple function to be able for the user to click on the link and download the pdf.
The size of the pdf is 6.3MB and it was perfectly downloading fine the first few hours after i wrote this code and checked it in the browser but when I opened my website on another PC the download caused a failed-network error, came back to my PC to check and it caused the same network error in my PC as well.

Although it is working completely fine on Microsoft edge but in chrome, it is downloading till 3-4MB and then a network error is caused.

Sometimes, it acts so weirdly that I download it a couple of times and it downloads, and after two or three successful downloads, when I download it again there is failed network error again.

Below is the simple code I am using to download the pdf

...

```
<a href="https://website.com/material/bro/22.pdf" download>
```

..

Comment: It's really hard to debug with the information you've provided. You are lacking sufficient context and your example is difficult to reproduce. Please read [ask] before posting questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and even used this URL https://website.com/material/bro/22.pdf to download the file, but website.com gave me a HTTP 404 - File not found error. I even used a VPN.

the problem is the pdf file you are trying to download might be removed.

try another link and see if the problem is with the browser or URL.